# make viewpagerindicator fragment startup just opened, clicked or swiped and do the loading?

Tags: android, fragment, viewpagerindicator

I use viewpagerindicator, at startup this activity, looks all fragment is loading. 
I want when a fragment startup just opened, clicked or swiped and do the loading.
And a fragment that has not been opened will be loading when opened, click or swipe later. how it?

this my code adapter viewpager

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class ViewAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private Context _context;
    String[] page_titles;

    public ViewAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, String[] page_title){
        super(fm);
        _context = context;
        this.page_titles = page_title;
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Fragment f = new Fragment();

        switch(position){
        case 0:
            f = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            break;

        case 1:
            f = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        case 2:
            f = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            break;

        }

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return page_titles.length;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return page_titles[position];
    }



}
```

Sorry for my english..

Answer (score 0):

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

on your pager set the off screen page limit, defaults to all pages, you probably want 2 so that the page next to your current tab will be loaded before you swipe to it. Take a look at the documentation for that Method for more info

Comment: before this, i has set pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); cz my tab count 3. its make my fragment all look loading together, but previous fragment not load again. If i set set pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); my previous fragment always load again...

but i want to juts clicked or focussed fragment is loading  and if back previous fragment to not load again